# I keep on getting this error after the message has sent "throw new Error('undefined is not a valid uri or options object.')"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This code is written in discord.js and is meant to search anything inputted using the command ?search ______, it will output the desired result then spit out throw new Error('undefined is not a valid uri or options object.') and stop working thanks.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("?search")) {
        var search = {
            url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + (message.content.replace('?search ', '')),
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "text/html",
                "User-Agent": "Chrome"
            }
        };
    };


    request(search, function(error, response, responseBody) {
        if (error) {
            return;
        }


        $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);


        var links = $(".image a.link");

        var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));

        console.log(urls);

        if (!urls.length) {
   
            return;
        }

        const embed = new MessageEmbed();
        embed.setTitle("Search incommminggggg");
        embed.setColor("#00ffff");
        embed.setImage( urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
        message.channel.send(embed);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is missing where the error is thrown, but I assume it is on this line:

> ```
> request(search, function(error, response, responseBody) {...});
> ```

The reason is quite simple `search` is `undefined`. This happens when your if statement does not match.

```
if (message.content.startsWith("?search")) {
    var search = {...};
};
```

If a `message` doesn't start with `"?search"`, then the `search` variable is never set and will be `undefined`.

---

Make sure `search` is set either way:

```
if (message.content.startsWith("?search")) {
    var search = {...};
} else {
    var search = {...};
};
```

Or if you don't need to do anything if the message does not start with `"?search"` you can use a guard clause to exit the callback early.

```
if (!message.content.startsWith("?search")) return;
var search = {...};
```

Comment: @samleews By making sure `search` is set. I've updated the answer.